# jQuery - setInterval() function w/ .animate() is slow

Tags: jquery, setinterval

This used to work, but it stopped all of a sudden and I'm not sure what's changed.

Overview: We have some html...

```
<div id="side">
  <ul id="photos">
    <li><img... </li>
    <li><img... </li>
    <li><img... </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```

There is a div of fixed height, `position:fixed` and `overflow:hidden`, within it there is a `<ul>` with a height greater than that of the containing `<div>` and `position;absolute`. The idea is that when the user hovers toward the bottom of `#side`, `#photos` scrolls up. I have it set up to scroll faster ~5px, toward the edges and slower ~1px toward the middle.

The problem is that it move -really- slowly. like it will move up 1 pixel and then wait and then move up another pixel. I set the interval to 10, which should be pretty fast, and worked previously fairly well.

So here's the script, the relivant function is the `setInterval()` at the end, the rest is provided just in case.

```
    var move_up, move_dn,
    hoverInterval,
    yPos,           //y position on slider
    objHeight,      //Height of slider
    posPercent;     //y axis percent on the slider


function movable(){
    container = $("#side");
    slider    = $("#photos");
    position  = slider.position().top;
    limit     = 0 - slider.height() + container.height()
    if(position >= 0)
        {return('top');}
    else if(position <= limit)
        {return('bottom');}
}

function scroll_div(a){ //a=amount to move
    $("#photos").animate({"top":"-="+a+"px"},"slow","easeOutExpo").stop("true","true");
}   

function move_div(){
    place = movable();
    move = (Math.pow(((100*yPos)/objHeight)-50,3)/20000);
    if (move < 0){
        if (place != 'top'){
            scroll_div(move)
        }
    }else{
        if (place != 'bottom'){
            scroll_div(move)
        }
    };
}   

$("#side").mousemove(function(e){
    objHeight = this.offsetHeight
    yPos = e.pageY - this.offsetTop;
    //offset = parseFloat($("#photos").css("top")) superfluous
});

$("#side").hover(
    function(){hoverInterval = setInterval(move_div,10)},
    function(){clearInterval(hoverInterval)
    });
```

Comment: Do you realize that you have setInterval set for 10ms, but it triggers the `scroll_div()` animation that is set to "slow" which is 600ms and you are stopping the animation every time you call it.  This doesn't make any sense to me.  For your particular purpose, you should run an animation to completion.  If you want to start another one when the animation is done, you can do so, but don't keep starting one, stopping it, then starting yet another one in the interval.  That's just enormously inefficient and not going to give you a smooth animation.

Comment: Ok, I fixed that, but it doesn't seem to be as smooth as it used to be. The only thing I did was change div#photos to ul#photos.

Comment: See my answer below.  What did you fix?  I can't help further if I don't know what the current code looks like.  You should be able to just use `#photos`.  No need for `div#photos` or `ul#photos`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your call to `.stop("true", "true")` is probably not working because you're passing strings instead of boolean `true`.  Looking at the jQuery code, for `.stop()`, when the first argument is a string, jQuery thinks you're passing a queue name.  Since there is no queue name called `"true"`, the call to `.stop()` is probably not doing anything.  Even if it did work, it should be before, not after your call to `.animate()`.  That means you are actually accumulating 600/10 = 60 animations all running at the same time because you're starting a new 600ms animation every 10ms.  Running 60 animations at once all on the same object is probably part of what is messing you up.

Your animate call should look like this:

```
$("#photos").stop(true, true).animate({"top":"-="+a+"px"},"slow","easeOutExpo");
```

And, you need to either get rid of the `setInterval()` call in `.hover()` or change its time to something that is more compatible with the 600ms animation you're doing.  Stopping and restarting your 600ms animation, every 10ms is not going to do what you want.

Comment: That did it. I had to rewrite the script and I guess never noticed the quotes around 'true'. Thanks.